# GCP load balancer health check not working properly

Tags: google-cloud-platform, load-balancing, health-check

I have a Load Balancer setup that routes traffic to multiple Cloud Storage buckets and an instance group for backend. The buckets seem to work fine but I just can't get the instance group to work. The instance works fine when I use it's public IP. But it just won't work through the load balancer.

This is my second time setting up the exact same deployment so not entirely sure where I went wrong. I looked at the documentation for troubleshooting, looks like something is wrong with my health check.

I have configured a health check which should work though, I set it to http port 80 / path. My server is returning 200 response code for that but for some reason, in the load balancer page, I can see the column "healthy" as 0/0 and in the backend service page, I can see 0 of 1 instances healthy.

[image: load balancer page image]

I even tried adding firewall rules for health check but still no luck.

Then I tried to get the health status using cloud shell and I get an empty status, not even failed, just empty. below is the result I got from cloud shell

> backend: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/project-name/zones/asia-southeast1-b/instanceGroups/prod-instance-group
> status:
>
> kind: compute#backendServiceGroupHealthkind:
> compute#backendServiceGroupHealth

Comment: Did you configure a Health check with port 80 when you created the Instance Group? What kind of Instance group did you create, Managed or Unmanaged? Does your LB is an HTTP(s) LB? Did you follow this documentation? https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/health-checks

Comment: Can you share the instance group configuration?

Comment: Yes, I used port 80, It's an unmanaged instance group. My LB is HTTPs, I did try HTTP as well but didn't work. I did read the doc. My instance group config has 1 instance under it with 1 port name mapping to port 80, network and subnet is default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This got resolved overnight. I guess there was some issue with GCP itself, I didn't change a thing and now it shows Healthy 1/1 and works perfectly.

I guess GCP load balancer is just unstable.